# PHP if not in array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have this code here:

```
if (in_array("Notecards", $array) || in_array("Poster", $array)){
    echo "Match found";
}else{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

My Issue is that Poster can be Poster 1, Poster 2, Poster 3, Poster 4 and etc.

If there away to say if Poster then space then a number is not in my array?

Comment: Can you post a sample output.Its not much clear what you are asking

Comment: $array is not sorted, but there could be values like Poster 1 or Poster 3 or Poster 2...I am just looking for away to say if "poster" then " " then any number is in my array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) like so:

```
if (in_array("Notecards", $array) || preg_grep("/Poster\s\d+/", $array)){
    echo "Match found";
}else{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

I took the liberty of assuming that you might have more than Posters 0-9, in which case `\d+` matches one or more digits (Poster 10, Poster 800, etc.). If you only require one digit, remove the `+`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

```
if (in_array("Notecards", $array) || substr_in_array("Poster", $array)){
    echo "Match found";
}else{
    echo "Match not found";
}

substr_in_array($str, $array){
    $length = strlen($str);
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(substr($value, 0, $length) == $str){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```